# How to return each week data as array in mysql query grouped by week?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is my data, you can have a test at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a51/4):

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (`day` datetime, `val` int)
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    (`day`, `val`)
VALUES
    ('2012/01/01', 465),
    ('2012/01/02', 896),
    ('2012/08/15', 678),
    ('2012/09/01', 324),
    ('2012/12/02', 74),
    ('2012/12/03', 65),
    ('2012/12/04', 35)
;
```

I try to query all the data and hope they return in an array `rows`, which is grouped by week, my code to do this is:

```
select *, week(day) Week,
  year(day) Year
  from yourtable
group by week(day), year(day)
```

unfortunately, it is not work as expected, I would like it output like:

```
rows[0]= first two records (as a array, such that I can get them by `rows[0][0]` and so on);
rows[1]=the next one record (as a array);
rows[2]=the next one record (as a array);
rows[3]=the next three records(as a array);
```

The point is that they are in the same WEEK.

Any help?

Comment: didn't get!, how come they are in the same week and your dates as 1-1 and 12-3, logically it is different, could you clarify that please..

Comment: Did u mean that my date should be in `2012-01-01` rather than `2012/01/01`? I think it is not the case, see my new test:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdcebe/1

Comment: What I mean by my previous message is the dates which given in the sql fiddle which you entered to the table is match the result, so could you please give the result you expect

Comment: with mysql it cant be done the way u want. U need to use the script to read the data and create the format the way u want.More over why doing group by ? it will only return one data. group by without aggregate function does not make any sense. If you want I can give u the query where it will return data group by week(day) and rest of common data as comma seperated in the same row. which u can manipulate with the script.

Comment: I have to second @AbhikChakraborty: use the week in order by if you need all rows or use aggregation-functions like `SUM()`on the desired values. Have a look at [this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a51/11) to see which rows currently are grouped. For all non aggregated columns MySQL will use a "random" value of the group.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I hope to manipulate the data in each group (such as display), so please give me your script mentioned here: "If you want I can give u the query where it will return data group by week(day) and rest of common data as comma seperated in the same row."

Comment: @TheConstructor thanks for your script, but I need to obtain all the data (not just `day` in the same week group), So can you please so kind to modify your code such that the records in a same week group  will return in a array?

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can do,

```
select 
week(day) as Week,
year(day) Year,
group_concat(val) as val
from yourtable
group by week(day)
```

This will merge common `val` with comma separation grouping by the week.

You can retrieve these data and use as per need.

If you need all as a row then u just select all record without any group by and then they all will appear as a row.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a51/14

Comment: Watch out that [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) by default only returns up to 1024 characters. If more characters would be needed the value is just truncated to the configured maximum character count.

Comment: Yea, I can figure out this after the discussion, but the problem will be, in general, the `val` may include `,` already, thus your method is not work in this case. Did there any way to return the `val` as a array?

I can do it firstly for `id`, and then query again to obtain the array, how did u think? Is this a good solution?

Comment: in mysql no it just result set... in php yes `$str = '74,65,35'; $arr= explode(',',$str); // now $arr is an array of values`. In other languages this should be done as well.

Comment: @TheConstructor yes group_concat_max_len and max packet len needs to be updated in mysql config :)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty and even then there is a maximum; it's just no longer 1024 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL does not have any array-type (or at least no GROUP BY-aggregator to create one) like Oracle I would use

```
SELECT *, WEEK(day) Week,
  YEAR(day) Year
  FROM yourtable
ORDER BY year(day), week(day)
```

and build the arrays when retrieving the result, creating a new row every time the values of Week and Year in the current row are different from the previous.
[Query on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdcebe/3/0)

To give you an idea how to do the grouping, this is sample PHP code to group the rows:

```
$plain_result = Array(
    Array('day' => '2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'val' => 465, 'Week' => 1, 'Year' => 2012),
    Array('day' => '2012-01-02 00:00:00', 'val' => 896, 'Week' => 1, 'Year' => 2012),
    Array('day' => '2012-08-05 00:00:00', 'val' => 678, 'Week' => 33, 'Year' => 2012)
);

$grouped_result = Array();
$previousWeek = null;
$previousYear = null;
foreach ($plain_result as $row) {
    if($previousWeek != $row['Week'] || $previousYear != $row['Year'] || count($grouped_result) == 0) {
        $previousWeek = $row['Week'];
        $previousYear = $row['Year'];
        $grouped_result[] = Array();
    }
    $grouped_result[count($grouped_result) - 1][] = $row;
}

var_dump($grouped_result);
```

`$plain_result` should be easy to build or alternatively instead of first retrieving as an array of rows directly do this while retrieving individual rows.